# Completed date not populating when field is updated

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Let me start by saying I am brand new to coding...like a couple of weeks new. I am trying to get a date to populate in a Google Sheet when a task has been completed.

When the Reviewed Status column has been updated to 'Complete' I would like to have the Review Completion Date field updated with the current days date. There are other statuses in the Review Status column (In Process, Not Started and Waiting Input) that I would like to ignore and not set the date.

I have the following code in Google Apps Script but the date is not populating when I update the Review Status column to Complete.

Any insights on what where I have gone wrong would be appreciated.

//Populate Completed Date when review has been complete//

```
const SHEET_TAB_NAME = "Data";
const COLUMN_TO_CHECK = 14;
const DATE_TIME_COL_OFFSET = -6;
const IGNORE_VALS = ["In Process", "Not Started", "Waiting on Input"];

function onEdit(e){
  const range = e.range;
  const currentSheet = range.getSheet();
  
  if (currentSheet.getName() !== SHEET_TAB_NAME) return;

  const column = range.getColumn();

  if(column != COLUMN_TO_CHECK) return;

  const dateTimeStamp = new Date();

  range
    .offset(0, DATE_TIME_COL_OFFSET);
    setValue(dateTimeStamp);

  const columnVals = columnRange.getValues();
  
  const dateRange = range  
    .offset(0,DATE_TIME_COL_OFFSET);

  const dateVals = dateRange
    .getvalues()
    .map((val, idx) => (IGNORE_VALS.includes(columnVals[idx][0])? val : [dateTimeStamp]));
 
  dateRange.setValues(dateVals)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable columnRange is undefined. Also it is unlikely that dateRange is a legitimate range because it was stored in a cell and I doubt that a range object can be stored in a cell of a spreadsheet.